# NullPointerException using Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure, attempting to write a function (all-bit-seqs n) that generates all bit strings of length n as a list. So if I were to call (all-bit-seqs 2), it would output ((0 0) (0 1) (1 0) (1 1)) in any order. However, I am getting a NullPointerException when I call the helper function rest-bit-seqs, and I can't figure out why. My code is as follows, any help would be appreciated.

```
(defn not-bit [x]
    (* -1 (- x 1))
)

(defn inc-bit-seq [x]
    (cond
        (= 0 (not-bit (first x))) (cons 0 (inc-bit-seq (rest x)))
        :else (cons 1 (rest x))
    )
)

(defn pow [x, y]
    (cond
        (not= y 0) (* x (pow x (- y 1)))
        :else 1
    )
)

(defn rest-bit-seqs [n, x, lst]
    (cond
        (not= x (pow 2 n)) (cons lst (rest-bit-seqs n (+ 1 x) (inc-bit-seq lst)))
        :else '()
    )
)

(defn zero-seq [n]
    (cond
        (= n 0) '()
        :else (cons 0 (zero-seq (- n 1)))
    )
)

(defn all-bit-seqs [n]
    (rest-bit-seqs n 0 (zero-seq n))
)
```

Comment: BTW, in the future try to find the *smallest possible amount of code* that replicates your problem. There shouldn't have been any need here for any functions other than `inc-bit-seq` and `not-bit`, and of course an example calling them with appropriate data. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because you don't handle the case of an empty sequence here:

```
(defn inc-bit-seq [x]
    (cond
        (= 0 (not-bit (first x))) (cons 0 (inc-bit-seq (rest x)))
        :else (cons 1 (rest x))
    )
)
```

so at one point you pass `(first x)` (which is `nil` for an empty seq) to `not-bit`.

the following fix solves this:

```
(defn inc-bit-seq [x]
  (when (seq x)
    (cond
      (= 0 (not-bit (first x))) (cons 0 (inc-bit-seq (rest x)))
      :else (cons 1 (rest x))
      ))
)
```

in repl:

```
user> (all-bit-seqs 2)
((0 0) (1 0) (0 1) (1 1))
```

the other things that are totally weird here, is your choice of `cond` instead of simple `if`, and uncommon formatting. I would consider rewriting the code this way:

```
(defn not-bit [x]
  (* -1 (- x 1)))

(defn inc-bit-seq [x]
  (when (seq x)
    (if (zero? (not-bit (first x)))
      (cons 0 (inc-bit-seq (rest x)))
      (cons 1 (rest x)))))

(defn pow [x, y]
  (if-not (zero? y)
    (* x (pow x (- y 1)))
    1))

(defn rest-bit-seqs [n, x, lst]
  (when-not (== x (pow 2 n))
    (cons lst (rest-bit-seqs n (+ 1 x) (inc-bit-seq lst)))))

(defn zero-seq [n]
  (when-not (zero? n)
    (cons 0 (zero-seq (- n 1)))))

(defn all-bit-seqs [n]
  (rest-bit-seqs n 0 (zero-seq n)))
```

(it's about style, haven't looked at overall code correctness)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
(= 0 (not-bit (first x)))
```

If `x` is empty, `(first x)` will return `nil`, so this will happen:

```
(= 0 (not-bit nil))
(= 0 (* -1 (- nil 1))
```

When you try to evaluate `(- nil 1)`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

The quick-and-dirty way to fix the problem is to get rid of `not-bit` and replace that condition with

```
(= 1 (first x))
```

*However*, there are much shorter/simpler ways to solve this problem. Here's one way:

```
(defn inc-bit-seq [[head & tail]]
  (if (zero? head)
    (cons 1 tail)
    (cons 0 (inc-bit-seq tail))))

(defn all-bit-seqs [n]
  (take (bit-shift-left 1 n)
        (iterate inc-bit-seq (repeat n 0))))
```

Another way would be to use strings:

```
(defn pad-first [n x xs]
  (concat (repeat (- n (count xs)) x) xs))

(defn all-bit-seqs [n]
  (map (comp (partial pad-first n 0)
             (partial map #(Character/getNumericValue %))
             #(Long/toBinaryString %))
       (range (bit-shift-left 1 n))))
```